# HTML / js. Need two different forms on one page submits separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I can't find any answer then ask:

I have to different forms on the page: the one is "ask for call" (placed on every page on the site) and the second is a simple "contact form" (placed only on contact page).

Both are validates without problems, do they are created for also good on the different page. Both has fields which are required. They has different names and IDs.

The error occurs when user on the contact page. There are two forms together. By the order contact is first. And when I use it, a mail sends.
But when I try to send call request with the second form on the page, it doesn't action because on the first form required wasn't filled or didn't match restrictions.

Why submit button from the second form takes data from the first?

Below forms in the order on the contact page and processing functions.

#### First form (contact)

```
        <form id="message" name="contact_message" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
        <div class="hover">
            <label for="message-name">Введите ваше имя:</label>
            <input id="message-name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя" title="Пожалуйста, введите ваше имя." required>
        </div>
        <div class="hover">
            <label for="message-email">Введите ваш email адрес:</label>
            <input id="message-email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="xxx@xxx.xx" title="Пожалуйста, введите корректно ваш email." required>
        </div>
        <div class="hover">
            <label for="message-text">Введите ваше сообщение:</label>
            <textarea id="message-text" name="text" placeholder="Текст сообщения" title="Пожалуйста, введите текст сообщения. Минимум 9 символов." minlength="9" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="contact_page">
        <button id="submit-contact" class="empty blue button medium" type="submit">Отправить</button>
        <div class="c-clearfix"></div>
    </form>
```

#### The second form

```
        <form id="call-ask-form" name="call-ask-form" class="full-width" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
            <label for="phone-name">Ваше имя</label>
            <input id="phone-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" minlength="2" required>

            <label for="phone-phone">Ваш номер телефона (только цифры)</label>
            <input id="phone-phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+41234567890" maxlength="16" required>

            <label for="phone-time">Время в формате ЧЧ:ММ, с 9 до 17 в будние дни, когда вы ожидаете звонок.</label>
            <input id="phone-time" type="text" name="text" placeholder="ЧЧ:ММ" maxlength="5">

            <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="call_ask">
            <button form="call-ask-form" id="call-submit" class="filled green medium full-width button" type="submit">Отправить запрос</button>
        </form>
```

#### JS

And here the `page_type` variable gets data from the first form every time I push submit on the second form. And switch cases on CONTACT, but CALL REQUEST.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit, #call-submit").click(function() {
    var proceed = true;
    var page_type = $('input[name=type]').val();

    //validation

    if(proceed)
    {
        var form;
        //choosing type of a message
        switch (page_type) {
            case 'contact_page' :
                // preparing data from CONTACT form
                break;
            case 'call_ask' :
                // preparing data from CALL REQUEST form
                break;
            case 'calculator' :
                break;
            default :
        }

        // ajax post data
        $.post('/assets/components/mailer2.php', post_data, function(response){
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message
                output = '<div class="error" style="background-color: red; color: white;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                output = '<div class="success" style="background-color: green; color: white;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            }
            $(form).append(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

Why this happens? Kindly asking you for help.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `$('input[name=type]').val();`, this will always try to find the value of the first input matching the name criteria on the whole page. 
But, note that both of your forms have inputs with the same name.

Javascript will not be very friendly when multiple elements have the same name. Instead, you will either need to rename them or ensure that you better reference which one you are trying to get:

The below code will get you the correct page_type: (Note that in events, `this` will be set to the current element which in the below case will be one of the `<form />` tags which you can use to only traverse it's children using `$(this).find(...)` as opposed to `$(...)`)

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  var page_type = $(this).find('input[name=type]').val();
  alert(page_type);
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
You are definitely right.